# Share SASS variables between files, without importing or referencing variables file?

Tags: visual-studio, sass, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to share variables between files, without importing my variables file in every file? Here's an example:

**Variables.scss**

```
$primary: #0000FF;
```

**HelpPage.scss**

```
#help-page-container {
    background: $primary;
}
```

**Core.scss**

```
@import "Variables.scss";

@import "HelpPage.scss";
```

`Core.scss` is the only file that gets compiled. All my single-page files, common CSS classes, and `Variables.scss` is included in this file.

If I want to use `$primary` inside my **HelpPage.scss** file, I would need to either do:

```
@import "Variables.scss";
```

or

```
/// <reference path="Variables.scss" />
```

Either one works. However, if I have 20 pages, I would need to import/reference the variables file at the top of *each and every one* of them, just to make Visual Studio happy and not throw a

> Undeclared variable

error at me.

Comment: Was just searching for a solution for the same issue, albeit in a different environment (PhpStorm) where even `/// <reference path="Variables.scss" />` is not possible, so there is **no** autocompletion unless `@import` is used ... during the research of the matter I found that there is on thing that LESS has over SASS is import by reference e.g. `@import (reference) "variables.scss"` which would do the trick here, but nothing like that in SASS and it seems like that won't happen: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1317

Answer (score -1):

Have you read this?
http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project

Essentially you would import `_variables.scss` and `_help-page.scss` **into** `core.scss`

This way *helppage* partial has access to all *variables*.

Comment: That does not work. When I open the help page SASS file, it will not know anything about the variables.

Comment: Maybe it's Visual Studio, I am using libsass through Gulp or Grunt.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely Visual Studio, which is why it's tagged.